# Why do browsers have 3 characters as protocol separator?

Tags: browser, uri

http:// vs http:

Either there is some historical reason or I'm missing something.

Comment: Anecdotally, that double slash is the one thing that Tim Berners-Lee regrets about his "invention" - one slash is enough and he didn't think of that when he made the original implementation.

Answer (score 4):

According to [RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738),

> While the syntax for the rest of the URL may vary depending on the
> particular scheme selected, URL schemes that involve the direct use
> of an IP-based protocol to a specified host on the Internet use a
> common syntax for the scheme-specific data:
>
> //user:password@host:port/url-path
>
> Some or all of the parts "user:password@", ":password",
> ":port", and "/url-path" may be excluded.  The scheme specific
> data start with a double slash "//" to indicate that it complies with
> the common Internet scheme syntax.

Comment: Thanks but I'm wondering where did the double slash "//" originate. One character should have been enough.

Comment: Well, the aim was to clearly separate web address from the protocol name. You are right, one character is enough, but it is quite hard to change this rule now.

Answer (score 1):

`//`                Indicates that a contact to a server is to be achieved. (For example, when sending email the notation `'mailto:<email address>...'`, without slashes, could be used). Note that this doesn't mean a connection between a browser and server. When a browser has sent a request, there is no connection between the browser and the server.

Comment: When a browser sends a request, there *is* a connection. Otherwise how does it get a response ?